# Reading multiple integers from line in text file

Tags: scala, console, stdout, stdin

I am using Scala and reading input from the console.  I am able to regurgitate the strings that make up each line, but if my input has the following format, how can I access each integer within each line?

```
2 2
1 2 2
2 1 1
```

Currently I just regurgitate the input back to the console using

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines) println(ln)
    //how can I access each individual number within each line?
  }
}
```

And I need to compile this project like so:

`$ scalac main.scala`

```
$ scala Main <input01.txt
2 2
1 2 2
2 1 1
```

Comment: Do you need one list of integers, or a list of lists of integers?

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable algorithm would be:

- for each line, split it into words
- parse each word into an `Int`

An implementation of that algorithm:

```
io.Source.stdin.getLines  // for each line...
  .flatMap(
    _.split("""\s+""")    // split it into words
      .map(_.toInt)       // parse each word into an Int
  )
```

The result of this expression will be an `Iterator[Int]`; if you want a `Seq`, you can call `toSeq` on that `Iterator` (if there's a reasonable chance there will be more than 7 or so integers, it's probably worth calling `toVector` instead).  It will blow up with a `NumberFormatException` if there's a word which isn't an integer.  You can handle this a few different ways... if you want to ignore words that aren't integers, you can:

```
import scala.util.Try

io.Source.stdin.getLines
  .flatMap(
    _.split("""\s+""")
      .flatMap(Try(_.toInt).toOption)
  )
```

Comment: Why `toVector`? But in any case, +1 to not using **Seqs** but rather any concrete collection _(I would just go with **List**)_. - in `2.13` you can use `toIntOption` instead of `Try(_.toInt).toOption`

Comment: Beyond about 7 elements (it will vary from one JVM and underlying architecture to another), `Vector` becomes far more memory-efficient than `List`, while having basically the same performance for `map`/`flatMap`/`filter` and friends (which is often all you want from any collection).  Prepending and `head`/`tail` decomposition are the only reasons IMO to use a `LinearSeq` over an `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: I doubt it, I am pretty sure a **List** is actually more memory and CPU efficient than **Vector** in most cases. The only reason for using an **IndexedSeq*** would be if you need fast access by index _(which is weird in functional code)_ and in such cases an **ArraySeq** is better than a **Vector**.

Comment: `List` by definition creates a new object for every element (about 30 or so bytes per element).  `Vector` creates a new array of size 32 for every 32 (or portion thereof elements) so about 200 bytes for the first 32 elements.

Comment: Yeah, but when you reach more than 32 elements, it creates 32 arrays of size 32 which is a lot of unused memory, so having a lot of small vectors is worse than having a lot of small lists. Also, again, in CPU vector is pretty mediocre. In any case yeah, agree to disagree, I like to use **List** they are simple and flexible.

Comment: It doesn't create 32 arrays of size 32 (as can clearly be seen from https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html#memory-use-of-immutable-collections): an `Array[AnyRef]` of size 32 is 160 bytes (for nearly any JVM in common use), the increase from size 16 to size 64 is far less than 32*160

Comment: Oh so I must have misunderstood Martin's explanation in the Coursera course, or things changed. In any case, that post is quite old, it uses Scala `2.11` many changed about collections in `2.13`, so it's not that relevant anymore. Anyways, again, agree to disagree as Li said, just pick one and continue with your life. I just have found **List** to be more useful in most cases and **ArraySeq** to be a better replacement of **Vector**.

Answer (score -1):

The following will give you a flat list of numbers.

```scala
val integers = (
  for {
    line <- io.Source.stdin.getLines
    number <- line.split("""\s+""").map(_.toInt)
  } yield number
)
```

As you can read [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-parse-number-int-long-float-bigint-from-string-in-scala/), some care must be taken when parsing the numbers.